# Linq criteria query

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Linq query for:

Record in MyTable has two child records, I want to check if either of these records have an Id from a list of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a start...

```
from mt in MyTable 
where myIntegerList.Contains(mt.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how that might be written:

```
var intList = new List<int>{2,5,223,55};
var query = from m in db.MyTable
            where intList.Contains(m.ChildRecord.Id)
            select m;
```